# Можно ли производить поиск по таблице, задавая диапозон id?

Tags: mysql, sql

Сделал небольшое открытие для себя и хотелось бы узнать, можно ли так делать?

Дано:
Таблица с товарами, где есть ID позиции в каталоге, статус товара и скрыт/показан ли товар.
Мой старый запрос, который считал кол-во строк в таблице выглядел так:

```
SELECT count(*) from goods where catalog_id=0 and hidden=0 and status=0;
```

(нужные индексы есть)

Среднее время исполнения этого запроса 0.3-0.5 секунд (в таблице почти пол миллиона строк).
Новый запрос выглядит так:

```sql
SELECT
  count(*)
FROM
  goods
WHERE
  catalog_id=0 and hidden=0 and status=0 and 
  id >= (SELECT min(id) FROM goods WHERE catalog_id=0) and 
  id <= (SELECT max(id) FROM goods WHERE catalog_id=0);
```

Среднее время исполнения - 0.05-0.08 секунд.
Честно говоря я был удивлён. По идее MySQL требуется выполнять больше сравнений, разве не так? И вообще есть ли какие-то возможные проблемы, которые могут появится при использовании такого метода?

Кстати, во втором случае команда `explain` выводит в колонке `extra` следующее:

```
Select tables optimized away
```

А, кол-во в колонке `rows` вместо 800 (как в первом случае) - 68. Хотя обе команды возвращают одно и то же число.

UPD. Структура - https://pastebin.com/q2F4vVd8

Comment: *(нужные индексы есть)* Это какие именно? *требуется выполнять больше сравнений, разве не так?* Не так. *кол-во в колонке rows вместо 800 (как в первом случае) - 68.* А Вы внимательно прочитали, что именно означает число в этой колонке? Убеждены, что поняли **правильно**? А если так - то как полагаете, почему оно столь сильно различается - и при этом в общем коррелирует со временем выполнения запроса...

Comment: Покажите DDL таблицы и оба плана

Comment: ID как primary key, catalog_id, status, hidden - индексы. Структуру добавил

Comment: структуру в вопрос добавьте, на кой она ссылкой на внешний русурс нужна?

Comment: а нужные индексы тут не 3 отдельных индекса по трем полям, а один составной индекс из трех полей.

Answer (score 0):

Индексы по столбцам `catalog_id`, `hidden` и `stаtus` имеют крайне низкую селективность. Большинство СУБД исключают такие индексы из обработки.

А вот выборка по диапазону уникального ключа как раз очень эффективна. Во всяком случае пока в диапазон попадает меньше половины таблицы.